# Sum of List of Integer values in Java (JDK 1.7)

Tags: java

Can someone please suggest, how to get the sum of first few list elements (integers)?

Note: My Java version: "1.7.0_07".

Below is the code:

```
    Integer sum=new Integer(0);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    sum=sum+list.get(i);
```

**Error:**
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Integer, Object

Comment: what kind of variable is list ?

Comment: `new Integer(0)` is a code smell, also you can use "new style for loops"

Comment: 'list' is ArrayList of type Integer objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe you have declared your list as a raw type, i.e.

```
List list = new List();
```

what you need to do is:

```
List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>();
```

or else you would have to typecast whenever you do list.get() like

```
sum=sum+(Integer)list.get(i);
```

EDIT: regarding your other problem

> If i define like --> 'List list', seeing error suggestion
>   like "Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source
>   level is 1.5"

Answer:

> my guess would be that while you run eclipse itself with jdk 1.6, it's
>   actually configured with a different default jre. see
>   window->preferences->java->Installed JREs and make sure that the
>   checked JRE is 1.6. (i'm hoping that you are getting this error while
>   working in some IDE) if the default JRE is indeed 1.6, chances are
>   that it's a project specific setting. see that the project is
>   configured to use the right jre.

Comment: If i define like --> 'List<Integer> list', seeing error suggestion like "Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5"..

Comment: my guess would be that while you run eclipse itself with jdk 1.6, it's actually configured with a different default jre. see window->preferences->java->Installed JREs and make sure that the checked JRE is 1.6. (i'm hoping that you are getting this error while working in some IDE)

if the default JRE is indeed 1.6, chances are that it's a project specific setting. see that the project is configured to use the right jre.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I changed my Compiler Compliance level to 1.6 and it got solved. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: if it's solved, please accept as answer, so others can stop posting duplicate answer. or do you want some more explanation about anything regarding your question?

Comment: Wait.. :) "You can accept an answer in 58 seconds"

Answer (score 2):

Your list should be defined as :

```
List<Integer> list = whateverCreatesYourList();
```

then you can:

```
Integer sum = Integer.valueOf(0);
for(Integer i: list){
    sum += i;
}
```

The important part is not using the raw `List` type but the fully defined generic `List<Integer>`.

Comment: +1 I would start with `int sum = 0;`

Comment: just wanted to show him the good practice of `Integer.valueOf(0)` rather than the `new Integer(0)` initialization. Plus maybe he did need an Integer object...

Comment: Do you prefer this to `Integer sum = 0;` ?

Comment: Well as an answer yes ... since I would have to explain what is auto-wrapping, or were you planning to leave it at that and not explain him how an `int` expression (0) was assigned to an `Integer` reference? But in my code ... don't expect me to type 1 character I do not have to.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(5);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(5);

    Integer sum = new Integer(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        sum = sum + list.get(i);
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: i didnt add any links to the answer. which link may be invalid? It is just a "to the point" code block.

Comment: you duplicate code from question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(10);
list.add(20);
list.add(30);
Integer sum = 0;
int listSize = list.size();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (i < listSize) {
       sum += list.get(i);
    }
 }
```